# Anaconda Jupyter Notebook Opencv not working

Tags: opencv, anaconda, jupyter, nameerror, pythonpath

Ok so to preface this, I am very new to jupyter notebook and anaconda. Anyways I need to download opencv to use in my notebook but every time I download I keep getting a NameError saying that ‘cv2’ is not defined.

I have uninstalled and installed opencv many times and in many different ways and I keep getting the same error. I saw on another post that open cv is not in my python path or something like that…

How do I fix this issue and put open cv in the path? (I use Mac btw) Please help :( Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following:**

1. Install OpenCV using Anaconda Navigator or via terminal by running:
   `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`
2. Now you should check if its installed by running this in terminal: `conda list`
3. Import OpenCV in Jupyter Notebook: In your Jupyter Notebook, run `import cv2` and see if it works.
4. If the above steps are not working, you should add OpenCV to your Python PATH by writing the following code to your Jupyter NB:
   `import sys`
   `sys.path.append('/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages')`

This should work.